# Rigidbodies going inside each other in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

How do I solve this problem?

[image]

Details:As you can see from the game view, the gems are dropping from the right-top of the screen. When they fall down fast and hit each other with the similar rotation, they go into each other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That gem doesnt look too bad to me. collissions can also go through objects if they are very fast.

Interpolation and continous mesh detection both increase the physics performance.

I'd recommend that you write 3 lines that increase physics performance when an object is going fast and switches it to normal when it is going slow. you can do a proximity test every frame to check for fast objects (physics velocity variable) to know what objects they approach, and make physics maximum for both fast and approached objects.

I'd use the same as you wrote, using the rigidbody velocity is perfect, except:

```
 private void Update ()
 {
     var vel = rgd.velocity;
     speed = vel.sqrMagnitude;//uses 5-20 times less processor power

     if (speed >= 4) // it's the same
```

Magnitude uses square-root maths which is one of the most expensive ops on a processor. Being a hawk about instances of every frame square root and divisions is what all advanced programmers do to streamline their code.

If you had to find the velocity of objects which aren't using physics, then you'd have to delete their current position from the last frame position every frame, to find their velocity vector which would be the same as rigidbody.velocity using posA posB variables to recall the last frame... i.e. for objects without a rigidbody.

Comment: If I set "Collision Detection" to "Continuous Dynamic" in Rigidbody component, how bad would it effect the performance?

Comment: mesh physics is wobbly on unity, interpolation sais where the object is in between frames because it's same as a stepping stone, and continuous is kindof the same, they give you adequate control of most scenarios, you budget 3-10 simple physics objects for every continuous one, i.e. it's worth  a few standard objects dont know how many. You measure your budget by knowing if 50 or 100 standard bouncy objects slow your PC down to 20 FPS

Comment: make an envelope for max phys objects on scene to keyboard control which returns to a function with 5-10 physics accuracy lines which can adjust physics performance using [ ctrl p+/- ] for min enhancement spd and for enhance on raycast visible objects in perspective. and make it print : phsx on level 0-10, and add to your function as you go along to make it lots of lines of little phsics animation mentalisms and end up with a 15 line function and copy and paste the same function to different priorities of the game list.

Comment: I see... Thanks a lot for explaining! :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code I wrote, and I used this on my object.

```
bool fast;
Rigidbody rgd;
float speed;

private void Start ()
{
    rgd = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Update ()
{
    var vel = rgd.velocity;
    speed = vel.magnitude;

    if (speed >= 2)
    {
        rgd.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.ContinuousDynamic;
    }
    else
    {
        rgd.collisionDetectionMode = CollisionDetectionMode.Discrete;
    }
}
```

Comment: that's good except that magnitude uses a square root, which costs about 20-70 multiply ops equivalent processing time, deffo not recommended in programming especially on multiple bodies. you do 20 per frame that's 400/2000 Flops spent. there is square magnitude which is used for comparisons when you dont need to know precise magnitude. hum i was downvoted yesterday on this page, my advice is the same as yours .erm. https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Vector3-sqrMagnitude.html

Comment: Actually, yes, you deserve it. So may I ask how I would do it without magnitude? You said "increase physics performance when an object is going fast", so how would I know if it is going fast without knowing the magnitude? Thanks.

Comment: I'll write that as in the answer field because it's easier to write code there.